# bs4 does not return full HTML

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am trying to get some information from a website using bs4 and requests.

the URL is: https://www.element14.com/community/community/design-challenges/in-the-air-design-challenge/blog/2014/10/26/firecracker-analyzer-index

I am trying to get to a specific div:

`<div id="jive-comment-tabs" class="j-comment-wrapper" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/html"> ..... </div>`

however when I use the following code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


URL = "https://www.element14.com/community/community/design-challenges/in-the-air-design-challenge/blog/2014/10/26/firecracker-analyzer-index"            
page = requests.get(URL)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "lxml")
print(soup.find('div', {'class': 'j-comment-wrapper'}))
```

I get **None** as result and I know for a fact that it is on the web page. I tried most solutions on the internet, but none of them helped me. Any ideas?

Comment: your code works for me. Have you checked the response status code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### What happens?

Website is serving these part of content dynamically, so you wont get it with request in that way.

#### Alternativ approach

Try to use [selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/getting-started.html), it will render the page and you will get your results.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome('YOUR PATH TO CHROMEDRIVER')
driver.get('https://www.element14.com/community/community/design-challenges/in-the-air-design-challenge/blog/2014/10/26/firecracker-analyzer-index')

soup=BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')

soup.find('div', {'class': 'j-comment-wrapper'})
```